# How to get bean values in jsp scriplets and store in a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts, scriptlet

```
<bean:write name="<%=(String) currentItr.next()%>" property="<%=(String) currentItr.next()%>"/>
```

The above code prints the values aka : `Nicholas...$100000...45....Actor`

How can i assgin Nicholas to a javascript variable?

I tried

`var audition = <%=(String) currentItr.next()%>.<%=(String) currentItr.next()%>;`

and it prints out the column header like so : `Name...Salary...Age...Occupation`

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this , if you are assigning string value then use ' ' or " " . For Number value what you wrote was correct .

```
var audition = "<%=(String) currentItr.next()%>.<%=(String) currentItr.next()%>";
```

Comment: it still doesn't work, it still show the column headers. is it because it is in a <logic: iterate>

Comment: post some of your code then only we can find out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

@LandLane Why don't you set this scriptlet value into hidden text box, and call the value from JS. How do you calling the javascript from java? If you are using **logic:iterate** tag means there may be n number of values like nicholas. Post your code, unless nobody can't diagnose it.